# Forces between two moving boxes

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I stumbled upon a problem which I have confusion in it .
suppose a scenario : [image]

From what I understand as of now :

1. the boxes will have an acceleration of 3 m/s^2.
2. 5 kg box will need 15 N , because we have 27 N and used 15 N , only 12 N remain.
3. remaining 12 N forces will be pushed on 4 kg box by the 5 kg box, however there is newton 3rd law , so there will also be 12 N reaction force along with the normal forces.

My doubt is how can the 12 N push able to give the 4 kg box an acceleration, if the net force between the two boxes is zero ?

Answer (score 2):

Your image shows too many 12N arrows, and it isn't clear what they mean. I see only two relevant 12N forces:

- The 5kg block pushes the 4kg one to the right with a force of 12N. This is a force that affects the 4kg block (coming from the 5kg one, but that doesn't really matter).
- According to Newton's 3rd law, the 4kg block exerts (as its reaction) a force of 12N on the 5kg block, in the opposite direction, to the left.

If we now look at the forces on the individual blocks, we have:

- The 5kg block gets the pushing force of 27N minus the reaction force from the other block, being 12N. It's subtraction because the forces have opposite directions, resulting in 15N left for the acceleration of the block.
- The 4kg block gets a 12N pushing force from the 5kg block and nothing else, so the 12N directly go into acceleration.

### EDIT

Inspired by @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere's answer, I'd like to add a reasoning how to find and calculate the 12N value of the forces between the blocks here. The value isn't arbitrary, but can be deduced.

First, we assume that both blocks will stay touching one another during our experiment. We can't take this for granted, depending on the type of forces applied (e.g. pulling on the 5kg block) it's quite possible that they separate from one another. But common sense implies that they'll probably keep in touch in our setting. We'll later find out if that assumption leads to any physical contradiction.

Assuming they stay in touch, we can treat them as a 9kg combined system, and the 27N pushing force will accelerate the system with 3m/s² to the right.

As we are interested in the system-internal forces between the two blocks, we need to sub-divide our system now into the two blocks.

Both blocks accelerate with 3m/s², so for the 4kg block, there must be a force, directed to right, with 12N. In our setting, such a force is possible: a pushing force from the 5kg block.

[If we had found to need a pulling force, that would have been a contradiction, as the blocks only touch and aren't connected, thus not being able to pull one another. In such a case, we'd have to drop our initial assumption of the blocks moving together as a combined system and to find a different movement model.]

Comment: Is that a typo in the first bullet point? (The text before suggests it is, and we're looking at two 12N forces.) The 5kg block "takes" 15N to accelerate by 3m/s/s, leaving 12N (from the initial 27) to exert on the 4kg block, leading to a 12N reaction. Or am I misunderstanding that bullet point? Everything else makes sense.

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere Oh yes, a typo. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the 12N force that's causing the 4kg block to move - it's the 27N force acting on a system of two boxes with a total mass of 9kg.

The 12N force and its reaction are what's keeping the boxes together.

Comment: Important aspect. The OP's question seems to take the 12N force for granted. To compute it, you need to first treat the system as a whole, before talking about the parts.